# RDBMS-independent way to get table primary key?

Tags: 7, database

Let's assume we have Drupal instance with second database connection. Tables in that second database are shared between many systems and thus **was not created using Drupal's schema** functionality. How do I get the name of the primary key, in a universal way that doesn't dependent on the RDBMS? Is there a way that will be equally good for all databases?

For MySQL I can use db_query and:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM {table} WHERE Key_name = "PRIMARY"
```

and for SQL-92 compatible ones:

```
SELECT pk.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME primary_key
  FROM information_schema.table_constraints pk 
  JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage c
    ON c.table_name = pk.table_name 
   AND c.constraint_name = pk.constraint_name
 WHERE constraint_type = 'primary key'
```

[Thanks to T I's answer on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809882/what-is-universal-sql-way-to-obtain-names-of-columns-in-primary-key#16810220)

What happens with Oracle or Apache Derby? I know I can find specific solutions, but I wonder if there is a Drupal way. I couldn't find one outside schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For non-Drupal tables

I don't think there is a cross-db drupal way to do this currently.

It would have to be added to the database schema class for each database type.
For example, see the [mysql database schema class](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!mysql!schema.inc/class/DatabaseSchema_mysql/7) and look at something like [addIndex](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!mysql!schema.inc/function/DatabaseSchema_mysql%3a%3aaddIndex/7).

Something similar could be done for `showIndex()`.
If it is added for all the different database handlers, it would then be able to be safely used.

Then a database API function would have to be added for easy calling.

For example you would need a `db_show_index()` function in database.inc like [db_add_index()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_index/7).

#### For Drupal defined tables

You can use [drupal_get_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_schema/7) and get the schema for a table; then, get what you need from that. It will return a schema as defined in [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7).

You might also be interested in some of the other [schema API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) functions.

The schema will only be what was defined in hook_schema though. It won't pick up anything that has been added or changed outside of that.

Comment: It is not an answer to my question. I'm asking specifically about tables **not** defined inside Drupal.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Fixing my answer.

Comment: No problem. Added emphasis in question to make it stand out.

Comment: I don't like your answer, because I don't like the facts it shows. But it seems I have no choice but appreciate comprehensiveness and just accept it. And hope in 8 it'll be different.

Comment: Yeah, It's probably not going to be fast/easy to get into drupal 7 at this stage. It would be relatively easy to get it into Drupal 8 though. There are probably other admin statements that are missing too.

Comment: So, which of us writes feature request?

Comment: Feature request created: http://drupal.org/node/2006800

Comment: Nice one, that saves me remembering to make on :)

Comment: I have this funny feeling it will be happily ignored, but at least it will not be a case of "nobody told us!".